# Compare lists Unions

Tags: c#, set-union, ones-complement

```
List<String> A = new List<String>();
List<String> B = new List<String>();
List<String> itemsremoved = ((A∩B)^c)-A;
List<String> itemsadded = ((A∩B)^c)-B;
```

I want to know how to do a complement of the union A & B minus the elements of a list. Is there a function to do this?

Comment: Linq has Union, Intersect and Except methods. This question is trivially googlable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ provides extension methods for [working with sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx).

For example, the complement of set `a` relative to set `b` will be:

```
var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 6 };
var b = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var comp = a.Except(b);
```

`comp` will contain elements `[1, 2]`.

Do a Google search for C# and LINQ set operations and you're sure to find plenty of examples.